# List objects in an AWS S3 bucket (deployed using Serverless)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I seem to be getting permission issues and can't find any SO answer to resolve this.

My Lambda function is simple (note -- I am using Babel to transpile):

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
import { success, failure} from "./libs/response-lib";

export async function main(event, context, callback) {
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const params = {
        Bucket: "mybucket",
    };

    try {
        const result = await s3.listObjectsV2(params);
        return success(result);
    }
    catch(e) {
        return failure({ status: false, message: e })
    }
}
```

When I deploy using Serverless and hit the endpoint it gives me, I get back a 500 error.

I have this included in my `serverless.yml` file and have turned *off* "block all public access" for the S3 bucket itself but it seems like I am missing more?

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:ListBucket
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
```

Comment: Thank you. Your iamRoleStatement helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so AWS' S3 methods are asynchronous, so I needed to have it return a promise:

```
.
.
.
const result = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();
.
.
.
```

Comment: The methods are "asynchronous"*  :-)